# Turn on 'Paste Remember Layers' with script

Tags: adobe-illustrator, script

I want to paste object remembering layers on new artboard.

Here is my sample.

```
function test(){

var copyOpt = app.pasteRememberLayers;
copyOpt = true;

...
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Help me, plz. :(

Comment: It  is quite common that you can not do this. PasreRemebersLayers is a attribute that returns a boolean value if you apply this to a variable its still juat  a  bolean assigning  to it has no meaning  to the original object.

Comment: What should I do to turn on this option? 

`function test(){
app.pasteRememberLayers = true;
...
}`

'Paste Remember Layers' option is not turned on with this code. Help me @joojaa