# How to toggle "Paste Remembers Layers" by an Illustrator Script?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

In an Illustrator script, I want to enable the "Paste Remembers Layers" option which is located in the Layers panel's flyout menu.

Apparently [this can be achieved in InDesign and its `Application` object has `app.menuActions` property for geting menus and then executing them](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/145192/toggle-paste-remembers-layers) but Illustrator has a different `app.executeMenuCommand` function which receives a string and executes a menu item. After searching references for menu strings like [this one](https://ten-artai.com/illustrator-ccver-22-menu-commands-list) , I couldn't find a corresponding string for "Paste Reembers Layers". Also the `app` object has a `pasteRemembersLayers` property which is read-only and is used to check whether the option is enabled or not.

Until finding a solution, I've resorted to checking the `app.pasteRemembersLayers` property and alert the user to enable the option when it's false.

Also I found a [similar question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/126126/turn-on-paste-remember-layers-with-script) that had no good answer and also my question expands a little more on the siuation.